# Odersky's Coursera Lecture: Why can't the type-checker infer value type Int?

Tags: scala, type-inference

My question is about Odersky's lecture 3.5 (not the assignment!):

The exercise at 19:15 asks: "What is the type of: `if (true) 1 else false`"

In his explanation, Odersky argues that the type is `AnyVal` because it is the most specific supertype of `Int` and `Boolean` (the types of the two conditional branches).

I am asking myself why the type checker is not smart enough to see that only the first branch is actually relevant, and the type could thus be inferred to `Int`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a similar question to why the following does not compile in Java:

```
throw new Foo();
return 42;  //unreachable statement
```

but this compiles:

```
if(true)
  throw new Foo();
return 42;
```

Basically the compiler has to stop somewhere. Especially the Scala compiler, which is already quite slow. Once it recognizes `true` as always passing condition, one might ask: what about: `1 == 1`, `2 * 21 == 42` or even `x == 7` where `x` is `val`.

It's hard to draw a line so the compiler simply assumes every `if` can have both branches. It's the responsibility of IDE or code validation tools to discover such impossible or probably incorrect expressions.

Answer (score 4):

I'd argue that you wouldn't want `Int` - that inferred types should not be dependent on optimizations, but rather on the text as written by the developer.  Otherwise, it becomes hard to predict what you'll get - granted, not in this case, but it's obviously more obvious than most.

Answer (score 2):

Because the type-checker does not make any assumptions about the execution of the program. It does not try to predict which branch of an if-statement will execute. In the general case that would not be decidable and this specific case will not occur often enough in practice to make any such predictions worthwhile.

Doing such predictions would also complicate the logic of the typing rules. If the type of an if-statement is Int and one of the branches has a type that is not a subtype of Int, that would surely contradict people's expectations - even if the branch will never be executed. In a way that would be the same as if the type checker would not complain about type errors in branches that it knows won't execute - nobody would want that.

Answer (score 0):

This got me thinking, because you can move where `true` is defined way up the chain. At some point the compiler needs to follow a lot of paths to come up with it's best guess.

this is always true

```
if (true) 1 else false
```

so is this, but at a higher level

```
val presetBoolean = true
if (presetBoolean) 1 else false
```

and so is this, but through an evaluated expression

```
val presetBoolean = (1 == 1)
if (presetBoolean) 1 else false
```

This is constant too, but in this case it is passing the reference to another object (and is the only instance in my program

```
case object CallWithPreset {
  def apply(presetBoolean:Boolean) {
    if(presetBoolean) 1 else false
  }
}

CallWithPreset(true)
```

There is overhead in the form of compile time with each inference. So, while I assume that in the trivial case it might be easy, it probably wouldn't be in other cases. However, if you allowed for some cases and not all, it would lead to each of those potentially having a different inference and could be confusing.

For example, if this worked:

```
val myType:Int = if(true) 1 else false
```

but this gave a compile error:

```
val presetBoolean = true
val myType:Int = if (presetBoolean) 1 else false
```